# Are there other definitions of Jacobi polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, orthogonal-polynomials, pochhammer-symbol

While I am reading "On some dual integral equations occurring in potential problems with axial symmetry" by C. J. Tranter, *Quarterly Journal of Mechanics & Applied Math* (1950) p. 414, the author stated that [link to the article](http://qjmam.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/4/411.short)
$$
\mathcal{F}_m (\alpha,\gamma,x) = {}_2F_1 (-m,\alpha+m;\gamma;x) \, ,  
$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is Jacobi polynomial.
From Wikipedia, I have found another definition which reads
$$
\mathcal{F}_m (\alpha,\gamma,x) = \frac{(\alpha+1)_m}{m!} {}_2F_1 (-m, 1+\alpha+\gamma+m;\alpha+1;\tfrac{1}{2} (1-x))\, ,
$$
with $(\alpha+1)_m$ being the Pochhammer's symbol.
Apparently the two definitions are not equivalent.

I was wondering whether other definitions of Jacobi polynomials have also been introduced in the literature.
Any clarification is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some references:

- [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiPolynomial.html)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials)
- [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.3)
- [Higher Transcendental Functions](http://resolver.caltech.edu/CaltechAUTHORS:20140123-104529738) (Bateman Manuscript), Volume 2, Section 10.8